# Firewalld rich rules

Tags: centos, firewalld, dmz

In a DMZ zone i have a CentOS7 server and i am looking to open only 2 flow :

1. Allow incoming traffic from 192.168.1.10 on port 2222
2. Allow outgoing traffic to 192.168.1.20 port 4444
3. Block everything else

I look to do it with firewalld rich rules, but i think that there applied only on oncoming traffic (need confirmation). I need help to found the right rule to apply.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RedHat docs have a section on [rich rules](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/configuring_complex_firewall_rules_with_the_rich-language_syntax).

From that it looks like you would need two `allow` rules, and a `drop`/`reject` everything else rule (assuming you're allowing the connections via the `tcp` protocol, and you will `drop` everything else, but replace `drop` with `reject` if that better matches your use):

```
firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.1.10" port port="2222" protocol="tcp" accept'
firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" destination address="192.168.1.20" port port="4444" protocol="tcp" accept
firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.1.10" invert="true" destination address="192.168.1.20" invert="true" drop'
```

This will get you most of the way there, it hasn't explicitly blocked the other ports on the two allowed addresses, but it might already be what you're looking for.

The rejection is simplified if the version of `firewalld` you are running supports the [`priority` attribute](https://firewalld.org/2018/12/rich-rule-priorities), as you could simply add a catch-all `drop`/`reject` with a higher priority after the other two rules.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --add-rich-rule='priority=999 drop'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's clear for me about the 2 first line, however can you tell me what that's the meaning of  `invert="true"` and `drop|reject` in the end of the third line please ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, in this case I should have been explicit, but it is intended to convey that depending on your use case, you can use either `drop` or `reject`, I'll modify the text

Comment: `invert="true"` sets up a rule that will apply to all addresses *except* the one listed. So in this case, if `source` is other than `192.168.1.10` or if `destination` is other than `192.168.1.20` (it is equivalent to the `NOT` rich syntax)

Comment: It's clear to me now, thank you very much.